# "no token found" when scraping from Promethues

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am using Promethues to monitor my Kubernetes cluster. All my microservices can be accessed using my HA Proxy.

My base Promethues config is :

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes_pods'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: http://172.29.219.102:8080
    role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip]
      target_label: __address__
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: 172.29.219.110:8080
```

Where `172.29.219.110:8080` is the IP & Port of my standalone HA Proxy.

The endpoint that I am trying to monitor using Prometheus is `/auth/health`.

When I do a simple curl command from anywhere, I see :

```
# curl http://172.29.219.110:8080/auth/health
{"status":"UP"}
```

But when Prometheus tries to do it, the logs indicate :

```
level=warn ts=2017-12-15T16:40:48.301741927Z caller=scrape.go:673 component="target manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes_pods target=http://172.29.219.110:8080/auth/health msg="append failed" err="no token found"
```

This endpoint is publicly exposed and requires no authentication what so ever. So why does Promethues say :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {"status":"UP"}

Prometheus requires data to be in its format, and cannot handle other arbitrary data. The error you are getting is a parse error due to this.

You should instrument your code using a [client library](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/), and have it expose data in the Prometheus text format.